# How to use the updateBatch method in codeigniter for updating existing DB field data + <Value>?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to increase the existing value in the database column by adding some value to a database field? In usual SQL query we can do like this:

```
UPDATE user_master SET votes = votes + 1234 WHERE id = 1000;
```

But I want to know how to do it in array of data passed to the updateBatch method

I tried like:

```
$array['id'] = 1000; 
$array['votes'] = 'votes' + 1234;
$builder = $this->db->table('user_master');
$builder -> updateBatch($array, 'id');
```

Comment: `'votes' + 1234` is trying to add a string to an integer. What happens with your code? Do you get error messages? Maybe you meant `$array['votes'] += 1234;`?

Comment: @user3783243
The array should contain all the values needs to be updated in the database table.
$array = [];
$array['id'] = 1000;
$array['votes'] = 'votes + 1234'; // That is the reason i kept it like this

But I am not able to find a way to mention the current field name + some value

Comment: You didn't mention what version of Codeigniter, so I assume it's version 3.
Check this : [CI 3 Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::set_update_batch)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official [Codeigniter 3 Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::set_update_batch)

You might try this, I've never tried it before :

```
<?php

$this->db->set_update_batch('votes', 'votes' + 1234, true);
$this->db->update_batch('user_master', null, 'id');
```